# Passing exact subelements to inexact object in function fails

Tags: flowtype

I want to pass an object with an exact object parameter to my function without having to specify an exact match:

```
/* @flow */
type a = {|
    b: string,
    c: number,
    d: {| e: number, f: string |},
|}

interface props { b: string, d: { e: number } }
function foo(x: props) {
  console.log(`${x.b}: ${x.d.e}`);
}

let var_a: a = {
  b: 'b',
  c: 0,
  d: { e: 1, f: 'f' }
};

foo(var_a)
```

Unfortunately flow 0.78.0 gives:

```
19: foo(var_a)
        ^ Cannot call `foo` with `var_a` bound to `x` because inexact object type [1] is incompatible with exact object type [2] in property `d`.
    References:
    8: interface props { b: string, d: { e: number } }
                                       ^ [1]
    5:  d: {| e: number, f: string |},
           ^ [2]
19: foo(var_a)
        ^ Cannot call `foo` with `var_a` bound to `x` because property `f` is missing in object type [1] but exists in object type [2] in property `d`.
    References:
    8: interface props { b: string, d: { e: number } }
                                       ^ [1]
    5:  d: {| e: number, f: string |},
           ^ [2]
```

I have also tried using type instead of interface:

```
type props = { b: string, d: { e: number } }
```

Now this can easily be fixed by specifying the `d` to be an exact element:

```
type props = { b: string, d: {| e: number, f: string |} }
```

This is rather annoying though as I would like to specify a minimum number of parameters in my function, i.e the `f` parameter is never used in `foo` and should therefore in my mind not be a requirement.

You can find the code in [Try Flow here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwCGYAvGAN4A+qAkAEYBcYAzugE4CWAdgOYA0qYQWADGjTgFcAtrVyt+1ACaNKYXGKky5YKIxYceYCgF9+x1Bhz5srONiYlyYBszZc+YJY7VgJ02WCMA1ChxTmF0djhObTg4AAoAD0ZrWyYASnIBESimOBhcADp4bjiAAwASMgSC2iNGSuqFAtwjUrSAblQjc3z0MAA3AlYAfQJGIlIyLOcAcloZ-kFRMAAGRY9lVUYARl5tRhmoGaCjTuDYuMGRgjTUIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experimented this further and determined why it happens, but I am not sure I am happy with the answer.

AFAICT this is a quirk of function subtypes only.

```
// @flow

const Clapper = (opts:{style:string}) => { console.log('clapping '+opts.style); };
const InvokeClapper = (fn:({})=>void) => { fn({}) };
InvokeClapper(Clapper); // fails :(

const Clapper2 = (opts:{}) => { console.log('clapping'); };
InvokeClapper(Clapper2); // works!
Clapper({}); // works!
Clapper2({}); // works!

const a = (b:{}) => 1;
a({});  // works
a({style:'string'}); // works

const a2 = (b:({a:number})=>void) => 1;
const a3 = (b:({|a:number|})=>void) => 1; // this and the above behave the same. why does it assume exact type for function param?
a2( (b:{a:number})=>{} ); // works
a2((b:{a:number,style:string})=>{}); // fails :(

const c2 = (b:({[string]:any})=>void) => 1;
c2((b:{a:number,style:string})=>{}); // works

const c3 = (b:(any)=>void) => 1;
c3((b:{a:number,style:string})=>{}); // works

const c4 = (b:({})=>void) => 1;
c4((b:{a:number,style:string})=>{}); // fails

// how can i say: a function that takes any object?
// or a function which takes any subtype of this object? any object more specific than { a:string, ... }

// this is the textbook example from Flow docs Width Subtyping page; very similar
const c5 = (b:{foo:string}) => 1;
c5({foo:"test", bar:42}); // works!

const c6 = (b:({foo:string})=>void) => 1;
// i guess this is a type=>type comparison, not a value=>type comparison
c6((x:{foo:string,bar:number})=>{}); // fails
c6((x:{foo:string})=>{}); // works

// this is one solution which seems acceptable but i am still confused why is necessary?
const c7 = (b:(x:{foo:string,[string]:any})=>void) => 1;
// what I want to express is: function b promises, for its x object parameter,
// to read/write only on x.foo. 
// or, if it attempted to read/write other keys, that should be a compile-time error.
c7((x:{foo:string,bar:number})=>{}); // works

// since exact match seems to do nothing here, i almost wish we could change its meaning,
// so that instead of forcing you to pass a variable with no additional keys,
// it instead forced the function b to not attempt to access or write to keys other than those in the exact match.
const c8 = (b:({|foo:string|})=>void) => 1;
c8((x:{foo:string,bar:number})=>{}); // fails
const altc8: ({foo:string})=>void = (x:{foo:string,bar:number})=>{}; // fails; but using lovely shorter syntax from docs

// reading chapter "Subsets & Subtypes" > "Subtypes of functions"
// it seems like, as in the doc example function f3,
// "The subtype must accept at least the same inputs as its parent, 
//  and must return at most the same outputs."
const c9 = (b:({foo:string,bar:number})=>number|void) => 1; //  this is the parent
c9((x:{foo:string})=>{return undefined;}); // works      // so this is the subtype

// i dislike this though.
// from my perspective, it shouldn't matter how many keys on the object in parameter 1.
// they should just both be considered an inexact object of any number of keys.
// while the parent considers it a sealed/exact object of just one key [that it cares about]. arrgh...

// going with solution c7 for now
```

see:
https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/subtypes/#toc-subtypes-of-functions

**UPDATE:**

I later discovered the next problem is that functions in an object type are automatically considered read-only/covariant (ie. `{ +yourFn: ()=>void }`), whereas the `{[string]:any}` map type automatically marks all keys read/write. So if your subtype includes functions, it will be rejected because the functions are read-only in the subtype but read/write in the parent type.

I worked around THAT by unioning generics in the parent--as an alternative to the map type--and, specifying generic parameters as necessary on function invocation.

ie., instead of:

```
const fn: ({ a:number, [string]: any })=>void = (x:{ a:number, b:number })=>{};
fn({a:1, b:2});
```

i went with:

```
const fn2 = <V>(x:{a:number} & V)=>{};
fn2<{b:number}>({ a:1, b:2 });
```

So, delaying the problem until invocation. It still provides a compile-time check. Working well so far. It seems very powerful! The Flow type system is stronger than in Java. What a twist!